# How to place the search filter beside the gridview header

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

In my application i need to display the search box beside the header column that is beside EmpName but it displays the search box below the employee name.How can i place the search box beside the header of the gridview.The screen shot that had attached shows i am getting the search box below the header EmpName but i should get beside EmpName.How can i do this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/quicksearch.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.search_textbox').each(function (i) {
                $(this).quicksearch("[id*=GridView1] tr:not(:has(th))", {
                    'testQuery': function (query, txt, row) {
                        return $(row).children(":eq(" + i + ")").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(query[0].toLowerCase()) != -1;
                    }
                });

 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" ShowHeader="true" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="EmpId" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound" UseAccessibleHeader ="true">
                            <AlternatingRowStyle Width="80px" />
                            <Columns>

                                <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpName" HeaderText="EmpName" ReadOnly="true" ItemStyle-Width="100"  />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Designation" HeaderText="Designation" ReadOnly="true" ItemStyle-Width="100" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="salary" HeaderText="Salary" ReadOnly="true" ItemStyle-Width="100" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="notes" HeaderText="Notes" ItemStyle-Width="150" />

                                <%--                    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" CancelText="" DeleteText="" EditText='<%#Eval("notes").ToString()=="" ? "add" : "edit" %>' UpdateText='<%# Eval("notes")%>' />--%>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Button CommandName="Edit" runat="server" Text='<%# (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("notes").ToString()))  ? "Add":"Edit"%>' ID="btnAdd" />
                                        <asp:Button CommandName="Update" Visible="false" runat="server" Text='<%# (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("notes").ToString()))  ? "Save":"Update"%>' ID="btnUpdate" />
                                        <%-- <asp:Button CommandName="Cancel" Visible="false" runat="server" Text="Cancel" ID="btnCancel" />--%>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>

                        </asp:GridView>
            });
        });
    </script>
  protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);
            //for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
            //{
                TableHeaderCell cell = new TableHeaderCell();
                TextBox txtSearch = new TextBox();
                txtSearch.Attributes["Search Box"] = GridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText;
                txtSearch.CssClass = "search_textbox";
                cell.Controls.Add(txtSearch);
                row.Controls.Add(cell);
            //}
            GridView1.HeaderRow.Parent.Controls.AddAt(1, row);
        }
    }
```